# my state get filled and get empty again ? React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello I am having a little problem here, I am trying to render data in my component, here is my component :

```
// Store data in the global state
const mapStateToProps = ({ moduleState }) => ({
    operationsContrat: moduleState.contrat.operationsContrat
});

// execute the action
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getOperationContrat: (...args) => 
          dispatch(getOperationContrat(...args))
    };
};

class Operations extends Component {

state = {
    data: []
};

// Nod used
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.operationsContrat.data.length === 0) {
        this.props.getOperationContrat(4000003);
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.operationsContrat.loading && !nextProps.operationsContrat.loading) {
        this.setState({ data: nextProps.operationsContrat.data });
    }
}
render() {
    console.log("operations");
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
        <Fragment />
    );
}
}
```

So I get the data and then my state.data is empty again, whch caused me a problem, because No data is displayed, here is what I see in my console : 
[image]

So what happens is that my componentWillReceiveComponent is not executed when my render method is executed the last time, I know what happened I guess but I dont know how to solve the problem..

I can provide any needed code if you need it to understand more the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why `setState` after load?  Shouldn't you be able to just connect props?

Comment: Davin : How ? I write something like this : state = { data: this.props.operation.data } ?

Comment: I want to know why my render method is executed multiple times too ?